# How to get MultipleView Type by using CursorRecyclerViewAdapter?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, adapter

Am having a doubt that how to use multipleView Type using CursorRecyclerViewAdapter I can Use the two layout but am getting header for only first item not for all items how to do this so far what have i tried is:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.amulyakhare.textdrawable.TextDrawable;
import com.amulyakhare.textdrawable.util.ColorGenerator;

import java.util.List;

import model.CustomerModel;
import timertracker.precision.timetracker.R;
import timertracker.precision.timetracker.RecyclerViewFastScroller;

public class CustomerListAdapter extends CursorRecycleViewAdapter<CustomerListAdapter.ViewHolder>  implements View.OnClickListener , RecyclerViewFastScroller.BubbleTextGetter{
    int position;
    Cursor cursor;
    ColorGenerator generator = ColorGenerator.MATERIAL;
    private OnItemClickListener onItemClickListener;
    List<CustomerModel>list;
    public static final int ITEM_TYPE_NORMAL = 1;
    public static final int ITEM_TYPE_HEADER = 0;    

    public CustomerListAdapter(Context mContext, Cursor cursor) {
        super(mContext, cursor);    
    }

    public void setOnItemClickListener(final OnItemClickListener onItemClickListener) {
        this.onItemClickListener = onItemClickListener;
    }

    @Override
    public String getTextToShowInBubble(int pos) {
        return Character.toString(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(CustomerModel.Customer_Name)).charAt(0));
    }

    public static class MyViewHolder extends ViewHolder {
        TextView textname;
        TextView status;
        TextView textphnum;
        TextView textdegree;
        TextView textemail;
        ImageView call;
        TextView header;
        public MyViewHolder(final View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
                this.textname = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.subject);
                this.status = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.customerstatus);
                this.textemail = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.username);
                this.textdegree = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.status);
                this.call = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);    
        }
    }

    public static class Headers extends ViewHolder {
      TextView header;
        public Headers(final View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            this.header = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.header); 

        }
    }
    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
      if(position==ITEM_TYPE_NORMAL)
        return 1;

        return 0;    
    }

  public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public ViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                           int viewType) {
        if(viewType==ITEM_TYPE_NORMAL){
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.customeradapterview, parent, false);

        MyViewHolder myViewHolder = new MyViewHolder(view);
        view.setOnClickListener(this);
        return myViewHolder;
        }
        else if(viewType==ITEM_TYPE_HEADER){
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.header, parent, false);
             Headers headers = new Headers(view);
             return headers;
        }
        return null;
    }    

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, Cursor cursor) {
           String  customrename = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(CustomerModel.Customer_Name));
        String email=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(CustomerModel.Customer_EmailID));
        if(holder.getItemViewType()==1) {
            MyViewHolder holders=(MyViewHolder)holder;
            TextView textViewName = holders.textname;
            TextView textstatus = holders.status;
            TextView textphnumbr = holders.textdegree;
            TextView textemail=holders.textemail;
          //  ImageView call=holders.call;
            if (email.length() >= 20) {
                String s = email.substring(0, 20) + "...";
                textemail.setText(s);
            } else {
                textemail.setText(email);
            }
            //textemail.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(CustomerModel.Customer_EmailID)));
            String status = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(CustomerModel.Customer_Status));
            if (status.equals("Active")) {
                textstatus.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#006400"));
            } else {
                textstatus.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#8B0000"));
            }
            textstatus.setText(status);
            textphnumbr.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(CustomerModel.Customer_MobileNumber)));
            String s1 = customrename.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + customrename.substring(1).toLowerCase();
            textViewName.setText(s1);
            ColorGenerator generator = ColorGenerator.DEFAULT;
            String com = s1.substring(0, 1);
            TextDrawable drawable = TextDrawable.builder()
                    .buildRound((com).toUpperCase(), generator.getRandomColor());
            holders.call.setImageDrawable(drawable);

        }
        else if(holder.getItemViewType()==0) {
            Headers header=(Headers)holder;
            String s1 = customrename.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + customrename.substring(1).toLowerCase();
            String com = s1.substring(0, 1);
            header.header.setText(com);    
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        final RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) v.getParent();
        position = recyclerView.getChildLayoutPosition(v);
        if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
            final Cursor cursor = this.getItem(position);
            this.onItemClickListener.onItemClicked(cursor);
        }    
    }

    public interface OnItemClickListener {
        void onItemClicked(Cursor cursor);
    }    
}
```

How to get recyclerview header for all items how can i achieve this.

Here is my Logcat Message if i remove Condition in OnbindViewHolder:

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                           Process: timertracker.precision.timetracker, PID: 28124
>                                                                                           java.lang.ClassCastException: Adapters.CustomerListAdapter$Headers
>   cannot be cast to Adapters.CustomerListAdapter$MyViewHolder
>                                                                                               at
>   Adapters.CustomerListAdapter.onBindViewHolder(CustomerListAdapter.java:123)
>                                                                                               at
>   Adapters.CustomerListAdapter.onBindViewHolder(CustomerListAdapter.java:26)
>                                                                                               at
>   Adapters.CursorRecycleViewAdapter.onBindViewHolder(CursorRecycleViewAdapter.java:77)
>                                                                                               at
>   android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:5471)
>                                                                                               at
>   android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:5504)
>                                                                                               at
>   android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:4741)
>                                                                                               at
>   android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:4617)
>                                                                                               at
>   android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:1994)
>                                                                                               at
>   android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1390)
>                                                                                               at
>   android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1353)
>                                                                                               at
>   android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:574)
>                                                                                               at
>   android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3028)
>                                                                                               at
>   android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:2906)
>                                                                                               at
>   android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:3283)
>                                                                                               at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14845)
>                                                                                               at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
>                                                                                               at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1055)
>                                                                                               at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14845)
>                                                                                               at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
>                                                                                               at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1671)
>                                                                                               at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1525)
>                                                                                               at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
>                                                                                               at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14845)
>                                                                                               at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
>                                                                                               at
>   android.support.design.widget.HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.layoutChild(HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.java:122)
>                                                                                               at
>   android.support.design.widget.ViewOffsetBehavior.onLayoutChild(ViewOffsetBehavior.java:42)
>                                                                                               at
>   android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior.onLayoutChild(AppBarLayout.java:1192)
>                                                                                               at
>   android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onLayout(CoordinatorLayout.java:814)
>                                                                                               at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14845)
>                                                                                               at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
>                                                                                               at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
>                                                                                               at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
>                                                                                               at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14845)
>                                                                                               at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
>                                                                                               at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1671)
>                                                                                               at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1525)
>                                                                                               at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
>                                                                                               at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14845)
>                                                                                               at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
>                                                                                               at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
>                                                                                               at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
>                                                                                               at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14845)
>                                                                                               at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
>                                                                                               at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1671)
>                                                                                               at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1525)
>                                                                                               at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
>                                                                                               at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14845)
>                                                                                               at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
>                                                                                               at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
>                                                                                               at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
>                                                                                               at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14845)
>                                                                                               at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
>                                                                                               at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2033)
>                                                                                               at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1790)
>                                                                                   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1046)
>                                                                                             at android.view.Vie

Comment: You want to add headers to all items in the `RecyclerView`? Then just remove the conditions in your `onCreateView` and initialize each item with header.

Comment: am getting null pointer excpetion how to do this

Comment: Then add your Logs.

Comment: just please take a look at it @Abbas i think my problem is with getItemViewType method how to return header and item based on adding headers to all items

Comment: Well the Logs say it all. Do you want `Header` to extend `CustomerListAdapter.ViewHolder` (`Header` should have everything defined in `CustomerListAdapter.ViewHolder`) or `RecycleView.ViewHolder`?

Comment: Like I said earlier if you want to add Headers to all the items in the list then there is no point in overriding `getItemViewType()` method since all the views are exactly the same.

Comment: even after removing that method am getting class cast exception error ; Adapters.CustomerListAdapter$Headers cannot be cast to Adapters.CustomerListAdapter$MyViewHolder how to solve this

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122268/discussion-between-abbas-and-m-yogeshwaran).

Comment: is there any third party library for this

Comment: your getItemViewType() method implementation does not differentiate between header view and normal item view.
it should be as follows:
 @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        if (getItem(position)) {
            return HEADER_VIEW;
        } else if (getItem(position) instanceof NormalItem) {
            return NORMAL_VIEW;
    }
private int getItemViewType(Cursor cursor) { 
    String type = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("type")); 
    if (type.equals("1")) { 
        return 0; 
    } else { 
        return 1; 
    } 
}

Comment: can you please elaborate @Rajendra

Comment: what does type refer too

Answer (score 0):

Here is the complete Solution:

```
    public static final int HEADER_VIEW = 0;
        public static final int NORMAL_VIEW = 1;
private String headerName="";

    getItemViewType(Cursor cursor) { 
    //Based on your Header and Item view condition return either the header view or normal view.
 String  customrename = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(CustomerModel.Customer_Name));
     String s1 = customrename.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + customrename.substring(1).toLowerCase();
            String headerNameTemp = s1.substring(0, 1);
             if(headerNameTemp.equals(headerName))
{
return NORMAL_VIEW; 
}
else
{
headerName=headerNameTemp;
return HEADER_VIEW; 
}
} 

    @Override 
    public int getItemViewType(int position) { 
        Cursor cursor = (Cursor) getItem(position); 
        return getItemViewType(cursor); 
    }
```

Hope it will help.

Comment: what does type comes from

Comment: in this code type is just differentiating between Header and Item, can you please explain which field in your cursor decide whether it is normal view or Header view ?

Comment: there is no such thing

Comment: cursor indexbound exception

Comment: complete log please

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122278/discussion-between-m-yogeshwaran-and-rajendra).